# Overriding Default CSS in ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit's TabContainer Control

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the ASP.NET AJAX TabContainer control in a web application. I've placed images in the headers for each tab rather than using text - but the images are truncated b/c the default CSS for TabContainer states that the header is only 13px high:

```
.ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_tab 
 {
    height:13px;
    padding:4px;
    margin:0px;
    background:url("tab.gif") repeat-x;
  }
```

I have a CSS file I'm using and have added the following line to override that contained in the default CSS for TabContainer:

```
.ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_tab 
 {
    height:83px;
    padding:4px;
    margin:0px;
    background:url("tab.gif") repeat-x;
  }
```

But it is still using the default 13px, why?

You can see the default css file here: [Default CSS File](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/820f953f86eb#Client/MicrosoftAjax.Extended/Tabs/Tabs.css)

Comment: The only way I have found to overcome this is to download the AJAX toolkit source code and strip out the crap so the controls are actually usable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of messing around, I got it working, though I'm not entirely sure what I did...

I think, I had to:

1. Manually add CssClass to ajaxToolkit:TabContainer, as even when setting it via the properties it didn't seem to generate.
2. I tried overriding the class ajax__tab_xp, but that didn't work, so I created a new class called ajax__custom and that worked. So my CSS in the end looked like:

   ```
   .ajax__custom .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_tab
   {
       height: 100px;
   }
   ```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I'm modifying the class ,  and I just need __xp  and 25 px is just fine

Answer (score 5):

Try using !important like this:

```
.ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_tab 
{
    height:83px !important;
}
```

by the way, If you don't change other properties of the default class, you don't have to retype them...

Comment: Thanks, although...unfortunately, that hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Dave,

I did the same thing. Copied Tab CSS and modified to my hearts content. Them I tried to disable tabs. This was working fine using default CSS. I thought something must be missing in my version. But checking generated source, it looks like TAB generates some js in page to enable/disable - Which, if we were permitted to to that on this project I would have gone with JQuery in the first place.

Save yourself some grief and use !Important to override default css if you dont want to go to javascript city.

Answer (score 0):

I am having to modify some web forms, upgraded to bootstrap and suddenly I noticed that some pages had

So The class I see generated is

```
class="ajax__tab_xp"
```

Thus based on answers above , I found that 25px is all I need

```
   .ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_tab 
    {
        height:25px !important;
    }
```

That should work for others hopefully.